# pandas - Pythonic way to slicing DataFrame with DateTimeIndex

Tags: python, pandas, slice, datetimeindex

This question uses `Python-3.7` and `pandas-0.23.4`.

I'm currently dealing with financial datasets that I need to *only* retrieve the data of each trading day between 08:15 to 13:45

### Variable Setup

To illustrate this, I have a `DataFrame` variable with `DateTimeIndex` with continuous minutely frequency declared as the following code:

```
y = (
    pd.DataFrame(columns=['x', 'y'])
    .reindex(pd.date_range('20100101', '20100105', freq='1min'))
)
```

### Problem Introduction

I want to slice the data from each `day` between **08:15** to **13:45**. The following code seems to work but I don't think it's very Pythonic and it seems to not very memory-efficient considering the double indexing at the end:

```
In [108]: y[y.index.hour.isin(range(8,14))][15:][:-14]
Out[108]: 
                       x    y
2010-01-01 08:15:00  NaN  NaN
2010-01-01 08:16:00  NaN  NaN
2010-01-01 08:17:00  NaN  NaN
2010-01-01 08:18:00  NaN  NaN
2010-01-01 08:19:00  NaN  NaN
...                  ...  ...
2010-01-04 13:41:00  NaN  NaN
2010-01-04 13:42:00  NaN  NaN
2010-01-04 13:43:00  NaN  NaN
2010-01-04 13:44:00  NaN  NaN
2010-01-04 13:45:00  NaN  NaN

[1411 rows x 2 columns]
```

**EDIT:** After thoroughly checked the data, the indexing above does not solve the problem because the data still contains the times after `2010-01-01 13:45:00` and before `2010-01-02 08:15:00`:

```
In [147]: y[y.index.hour.isin(range(8,14))][15:][:-14].index[300:400]
Out[147]: 
DatetimeIndex(['2010-01-01 13:15:00', '2010-01-01 13:16:00',
               '2010-01-01 13:17:00', '2010-01-01 13:18:00',
               '2010-01-01 13:19:00', '2010-01-01 13:20:00',
               ...
               '2010-01-01 13:35:00', '2010-01-01 13:36:00',
               '2010-01-01 13:37:00', '2010-01-01 13:38:00',
               '2010-01-01 13:39:00', '2010-01-01 13:40:00',
               '2010-01-01 13:41:00', '2010-01-01 13:42:00',
               '2010-01-01 13:43:00', '2010-01-01 13:44:00',
               '2010-01-01 13:45:00', '2010-01-01 13:46:00', # 13:46:00 should be excluded
               '2010-01-01 13:47:00', '2010-01-01 13:48:00', # this should be excluded
               '2010-01-01 13:49:00', '2010-01-01 13:50:00', # this should be excluded
               '2010-01-01 13:51:00', '2010-01-01 13:52:00', # this should be excluded
               '2010-01-01 13:53:00', '2010-01-01 13:54:00', # this should be excluded
               '2010-01-01 13:55:00', '2010-01-01 13:56:00', # this should be excluded
               '2010-01-01 13:57:00', '2010-01-01 13:58:00', # this should be excluded
               '2010-01-01 13:59:00', '2010-01-02 08:00:00', # this should be excluded
               '2010-01-02 08:01:00', '2010-01-02 08:02:00', # this should be excluded
               '2010-01-02 08:03:00', '2010-01-02 08:04:00', # this should be excluded
               '2010-01-02 08:05:00', '2010-01-02 08:06:00', # this should be excluded
               '2010-01-02 08:07:00', '2010-01-02 08:08:00', # this should be excluded
               '2010-01-02 08:09:00', '2010-01-02 08:10:00', # this should be excluded
               '2010-01-02 08:11:00', '2010-01-02 08:12:00', # this should be excluded
               '2010-01-02 08:13:00', '2010-01-02 08:14:00', # this should be excluded
               '2010-01-02 08:15:00', '2010-01-02 08:16:00',
               '2010-01-02 08:17:00', '2010-01-02 08:18:00',
               '2010-01-02 08:19:00', '2010-01-02 08:20:00',
               ...
               '2010-01-02 08:47:00', '2010-01-02 08:48:00',
               '2010-01-02 08:49:00', '2010-01-02 08:50:00',
               '2010-01-02 08:51:00', '2010-01-02 08:52:00',
               '2010-01-02 08:53:00', '2010-01-02 08:54:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

#### Workaround Attempt

I tried multiple boolean masking but the following code will truncate every `0` to `14` **AND** `46` to `59` minutes of each hour:

```
y[(
    y.index.hour.isin(range(8,14)) & y.index.minute.isin(range(15, 46))
)]
```

### Question

There must be a better way to do this in a more efficient manner that I might miss (or perhaps `pandas` has already had the function). What is the more precise/pythonic way to slice the data with `DateTimeIndex`? For example:

```
y[(y.index.day("everyday") & y.index.time_between('08:15', '13:45'))]
```

or even better:

```
y[y.index("everyday 08:15 to 13:45")]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this functionality is built in with [`DataFrame.between_time`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.between_time.html)

```
y.between_time("08:15", "13:45")
```

Comment: My my my... I spent my whole life searching for an answer right between my eyes. I thought the function would be called `time_between`, instead it is `between_time`. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

You almost guessed the correct function name. You can can use the function [`DataFrame.between_time`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.between_time.html) to achieve the desired filtering.

Example:

```
y_active = y.between_time('08:15', '13:45')
```